# Some properties of $L[A]$ (Constructible universe relativized to $A$)

Tags: logic, set-theory

**Question** 
We defined $L[A]$, constructible universe relativized to $A$ (definition below) and should now prove the following properties: 
1. $L[A]$ is transitive. 
2. All axioms of $ZF$ hold in $L[A]$. 
3. If $A$ is a set of ordinals, then the Axiom of Choice holds in $L[A]$.
4. Let $\bar{A} = A ∩ L[A]$. Then $L[\bar{A}] = L[A]$ and moreover $\bar{A} ∈ L[\bar{A}]$.

**What I know** 
I allready know that the properties 1.-3. hold in $L$, so I think I just need to show that they are definable in $A$. Is this right? But I am stil not sure how to do that. And for 4. I have no clue how to prove that.

**Definition** 
Given a set $A$ and a transitive model $M$, we set
\begin{equation}
def_A(M) = \{X ⊆ M : X \text{ is definable over } (M, ∈, A ∩ M) \text{ with parameters from } M\}
\end{equation}
where $A ∩ M$ is allowed as an additional unary predicate in the model. We defined
\begin{align}
L_0[A] &:= \emptyset, \\
L_{\alpha + 1} [A] &:= def_A(L_{\alpha}[A]), \\
L_{\lambda} [A] &:= \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} L_{\alpha} [A], \\
L[A] &:= \bigcup_{\alpha \in ON} L_{\alpha} [A].
\end{align}
Here $\lambda$ is a limit Ordinal and $ON$ denotes the class of all Ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

You need to literally repeat the same proof as you would have in the construction of $L$. There's no funny business about it.

For the 4th item:

1. Prove by induction that $L_\alpha[A]=L_\alpha[\overline A]$,
2. then conclude that there is some $\alpha$ such that $\overline A=A\cap L_\alpha[A]$ and it is a subset of $L_\alpha[A]$,
3. finally, use the definition of $L_{\alpha+1}[A]$ to conclude that $\overline A\in L[\overline A]=L[A]$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to interpret your idea, so let me leave a few instructions instead:

1. Prove, by induction on $\alpha$, that $L_{\alpha}[A]$ is transitive. For $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha$ limits the induction step is trivial. For successor ordinals $\alpha = \beta +1$ you adapt the computation for $L$ to this case (it's basically the same proof).
2. The inner model criterion comes in handy here: Show that $L[A]$ is closed under Gödel operations and almost universal. If you don't know the criterion or these terms, have a look at Theorem 13.9 of Jech's 'Set Theory -- 3rd millenium edition'. (It's a very handy tool to have, so it's worth your time learning about it regardless.)
3. Adapt the usual construction of a global well-order for $L$. The key is that $L[A]$ contains a well-order for $A$ (the membership relation) in case that $A$ is a set of ordinals.
4. Asaf handled this.

Comment: Asaf also handled 1–3, by the way. It really is the same proof as in the case of $L$.

Comment: @Asaf I try not to presume that people ask questions here without thinking about the obvious answers first. Based on this and the fact that OP asked for guidance, I thought a slight nudge in the right direction might be in order.

Comment: Well, the OP mentioned that they are familiar with $L$, and that they have an idea of how this should be solved ("definable in $A$"). I am guessing that the usual "lazy approach" (of which I am often a fan) of "let's reduce this to a previous proof, and not just repeat the previous proof" took over there for a moment (and it makes sense for it to take over, too, since one would expect somehow for this to be the "right way of doing this" rather than repeating the same proof). This is of course a good reason to ask online, but also a reason for my lazy self to assume the OP hasn't done this.